# Disk USAGE summary Report in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, diskspace

I created a report in sql server by right clicking Report->Standard Reports -> Disk usage by Table .In the following snapshot the you can see the unused space is ~23 and 20gb respectively .We have a lot of insert operation in this table during our nightly migration which might be causing it but not sure about it.

[image]

After this step i grabbed the database disk usage which is shared below 
[image]

The database disk usage says that around 8.23 is unused which turns around to 555gb(database size) * 0.0823 = ~45 gb and matches the table unused space.

I would like to get recommendation for the best practice under such scenario.

1. Should i reclaim the unused space of these table ?
2. Is the unused     space because of the index fragmentation and the
   regular insert     ,update and delete operation.How can this be
   avoided?
3. If  reclaiming the database unused space a best practice ,how do i         reclaim it ?

Thanks.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I would like to know the best practice in such cases ,should i be reclaiming unused space on a table or not specially when it combines to 45GB.If yes then how should i do it.Some articles says that unused space is good since the file size doesn't need to auto grow every now and then which saves a bit of resource .So i am not sure what is the best way to handle this.Also my query is mentioned above it point 1,2, and 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No. To reclaim the space, you would need to shrink DB. It will cause a fragmentation, so you would need to do index reorganization or rebuild, which is not without cost. There is no reason for that as DB will grow again. 10% of unused space in DB with many DML changes is expected and fine.
2. It can't be avoided. When you delete many rows, the space becomes unused till it's used by new INSERTs. Fragmentation is also another reason to have it. Check the fragmentation periodically and perform index rebuild (fragmentation more than 30%) / reorganisation (fragmentation is between 10%-30%).
3. The disk space is cheap today, so if there are no specific reason to shrink DB, don't do that.